# Cant submit form with AJAX on my Laravel site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am having serious problems trying to submit my form using AJAX within my Laravel site. Im about 95% sure it has to do with the csrf-token problem I see most people get. However with all the searching ive done, I still haven't been able to figure it out. I am brand new to Laravel too.

Whenever I try to submit my form I get this message in my log "jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8000/submit 500 (Internal Server Error" which ive heard has to do with this token problem. But no matter what i do, I cant seem to fix it with my token. Im probably just implementing it wrong so if any of you have some ideas on why this would be happening, that would be great!

This is where I call in my token

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

The head of my form

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="heroForm">
```

and my ajax call

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
$( '#heroForm' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var location = $('#location').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var upload = $('#upload').val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/submit',
    data: {name:name, location:location, phone:phone, email:email, upload:upload},
    success: function( msg ) {
    alert( 'msg' );
    },error:function(){
    alert("error!!!!");
}
    });
});
```

Im pretty sure the issue is within my ajax call

Comment: you should be looking at your server's error logs and the php error logs for more detailed information about what is going wrong.

Comment: Use server side  error reporting and you can inspect the full response in browser dev tools network also and read what it says